# How to esablish a Database SSL connection via .ODC file

Tags: excel, ssl, db2

I have been using .ODC files to get data directly and quickly from a database for years but we have been using a NON-SSL connection : Port number:  50000. We are now forced to use an SSL connection only: Port number:    50001.  When I change the port number in the .ODC file I get the error message below.... not mention that I have no idea how to link it to a SLL certificate. Sorry if I mistag this question. I am not sure how to tag it properlly. Also, I an using .ODC files with DB2.

[image]

Comment: Configuring a Db2-client on MS-Windows for SSL/TLS is documented in the Db2 Knowledge Center, for __IBM supplied Db2-drivers__. You will need an __up to date__  Db2 driver from IBM.  You will need to create a new ODC file.  Use connection-keywords SECURITY=SSL  and  SSLSERVERCERTIFICATE=\path\to\server_certificate .  This is __configuration__ not programming . Refer to documentation in Db2 Knowledge center.   If you are __not__ using IBM supplied drivers, different instructions will apply, so refer to your vendor instead.

Comment: @mao Thank you :)